# Multi-part Identifier could not be bound in where statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write a basic query that will change a value if data from two tables meets the right criteria. Selecting the data works fine with the where statement I'm using, but trying to Set the value returns the error "The multipart Identifier "imitmidx_sql.item_desc_1" could not be bound.

```
select 
   comp_item_no, 
   qty_per_par, 
   item_desc_1
from 
   bmprdstr_sql
Left Outer Join
   imitmidx_sql 
   on 
      bmprdstr_sql.comp_item_no = imitmidx_sql.item_no
update 
   bmprdstr_sql 
set 
    qty_per_par = '0' 
    where  
        bmprdstr_sql.comp_item_no like '68%' and
        imitmidx_sql.item_desc_1 like 'WIRE,%'
```

Using the below query, 2300 rows are affected, I would like to change those affected rows so that qty_per_par is 0

```
select comp_item_no, qty_per_par, item_desc_1
from bmprdstr_sql
Left Outer Join imitmidx_sql
on bmprdstr_sql.comp_item_no = imitmidx_sql.item_no
where comp_item_no like '68%' and item_desc_1 like 'WIRE,%'
```

Comment: What type of SQL and what version?

Comment: That's essentially two different SQL statements. If you're trying to do an UPDATE from a SELECT, you'll need to change it.

Comment: What SQL are you using?

Comment: @Shawn This is using SQL Server 2008 R2 on Management Studio 10.50.2550.0 I apologize for everything flipping around, you answered faster than I expected, I was still figuring out how to organize my post in stackoverflow!

Comment: And can you provide an example schema of the tables you're using? What type of data is `comp_item_no`?

Comment: As @Shawn has said, you have 2 statements in that batch, however, you can't reference columns from another statement in the same batch. You need to turn it into a single statement.

Comment: Sorry, pretty new to this, looking up how to even reply to that question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use a `select` statement to determine how many records would be updated.  But to do the `update`, you need to write the `update` statement so that it includes all of the criteria that you wrote in your `select` statement.

This includes both tables in the `from` clause, with aliases `x` and `y`, which makes it easy to reference them throughout the rest of the statement.

```
update x
set    x.qty_per_par = 0
from   bmprdstr_sql x left outer join imitmidx_sql y on x.comp_item_no = y.item_no
where  x.comp_item_no like '68%'
  and  y.item_desc_1 like 'wire,%'
```

Comment: qty_per_par is in bmprdstr_sql, and item_desc_1 is in imitmidx_sql

Comment: Going by what you provided I entered:

update x
set x.qty_per_par = 0
from bmprdstr_sql x left outer join imitmidx_sql y on x.comp_item_no = y.item_no
where x.comp_item_no like '68%'
 and y.item_desc_1 like 'wire,%'

This seems to have worked perfectly! Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome.  I hope it all makes sense, so that you are able to write these kinds of things in the future.  If the answer is correct, please mark it correct...

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using SQL Server 2008, you can do this with a CTE that easily limits the records you want to update.

***NOTE:** I changed the way you were preforming your JOIN. You are doing a LEFT JOIN and then filtering with a WHERE. This is pretty much the same as just moving that WHERE condition up into the JOIN and switching to an INNER JOIN.*

**SETUP**

> ```
> CREATE TABLE t1 ( id int, words varchar(10) ) ;
> CREATE TABLE t2 ( id int identity, t1ID int, morewords varchar(10)) ;
>
> INSERT INTO t1 (id, words )
> VALUES (1,'asfd'), (2, 'jklsemi'),(3,'qwerty') ;
>
> INSERT INTO t2 ( t1ID, morewords )
> VALUES (1,'fdsa'),(1,'qq'),(3,'yy');
> ```

**That gives us:**

> ```
> SELECT * 
> FROM t1
> INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.t1id
>     AND t2.morewords = 'fdsa'
> ```
>
> ```
> id | words | id | t1ID | morewords
> -: | :---- | -: | ---: | :--------
>  1 | asfd  |  1 |    1 | fdsa
> ```

**And to do our UPDATE:**

> ```
> ; WITH cte1 AS (
>     SELECT t1.id, t1.words 
>     FROM t1
>     INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.t1id  
>         AND t2.morewords = 'fdsa'
>     WHERE t1.words LIKE 'a%'
> )
> UPDATE cte1
> SET cte1.words = 'new'
> ;
> ```

**Which then gives us:**

> ```
> SELECT * FROM t1
> ```
>
> ```
> id | words  
> -: | :------
>  1 | new    
>  2 | jklsemi
>  3 | qwerty
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=bae7ef671acdea26eb64de3f52a37817)*

Comment: phew you just blew my mind with this. Is there any advantage to doing it this way over what James showed above?

Comment: @Travis I think it would completely depend on your data. I would definitely update my JOIN to perform the row limiting rather than filtering with the `WHERE` clause, just because I _think_ the optimizer might do a better job of building the result set you need. The CTE makes it dead simple to see exactly what you will be updating, but it'll be less portable (like MySQL 5 doesn't have CTEs), but it should work well with MS SQL Server.

Comment: Updated Fiddle to step through queries: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=c992dd7b4dd0ca1756070b654d9e17b2

Comment: Thank you Shawn, as you have both answered my question with different offered solutions I have marked both as correct. Thanks again!